# Anatomy of iphones built in contacts application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

In my iphone, in the section where I can make a call, I can view recent calls and I can also view my contacts.

I am referring to the contacts application.

I'm watching the stanford iphone vidoes, and they recommend creating a seperate NIB file for each view.

From what I understand, each nib/view will be managed by its own subclass of UIViewController.

Can someone, at a high level, describe what the contacts application might be comprised of in terms of nib's, controllers and views and how they would work together?

Answer (score 0):

The contacts app is, unfortunately, a bad example. It's functionality is implemented at a lower level in the OS, as it is shared between the address book app, the phone app, and it can be implemented in your own app if you wish. Thus, the app is really just another front end for the feature.

Basically, the app is a UITableView with search that sends you to a UIView containing a UITableView and some text / image fields. Of course, there are editing and creation buttons to handle CRUD, but basically that's it. Each page would have it's own UIViewController and NIB file (assuming Apple follows their own directions, which they may not) ;)

Underneath, you have a core data store, but there's no much complexity in the data structure there, either. If you really want to analyze the database file, that's possible as well.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you have a `UITabBarController` that handles the tabs along the bottom and the switching of the five view controllers. Each of the view controllers, with the exception of the "Keypad" tab, uses a `UITableViewController` as the root controller of a `UINavigationController`. And it looks like, for the most part, where you are in the `UINavigationController` "stack" is remembered for each tab.

Each of the `UITableViewController`s have a fairly simple implementation of the standard `UITableView`s. The implementations of `UITableView` are probably canonical examples of how to use `UITableView`s -- namely, what action to trigger depending on whether there's a disclosure button and what gets clicked.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, would there be any custom graphics used or is it for the most part using built in uikit controls?

Comment: I could be totally wrong on this, but the biggest thing I wish was part of the UIKit controls is the "Delete Contact" button when you edit a contact. I'm also not sure how they transition the "Edit" animation, that would probably require custom animations of various parts. I believe the sample code project, "iPhoneCoreDataRecipes", shows you a lot of similar effects.